# How to make postfix or mailman send outgoing emails on behalf of announce@example.com instead of announce@lists.example.com?

Tags: postfix, mailman

I have successfully installed and configured postfix and mailman and everything works correctly. The server FQDN is lists.example.com. My problem is that I would like mails sent to subscribers to appear as if they came from announce@example.com instead of announce@lists.example.com?

My system details are:
postfix 2.9.6
mailman 2.1.14
Ubuntu 12.04

Here is the most significant part of the postfix configuration (/etc/postfix/main.cf):

```
myorigin = /etc/mailname
myhostname = lists.example.com
mydomain = example.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#mydestination = lists.example.com, lists, localhost.example.com, localhost
mydestination = $mydomain $myhostname localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_protocols = all
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I finally got it after reading this very thorough HOWTO [here](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/).

1. in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` --> mydomain = example.com
2. in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` --> myorigin = $mydomain (i.e. the same - example.com)
3. in `/etc/mailman/mm_cfg.py` --> DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST = 'example.com'
4. in `/etc/mailname` it's OK to leave lists.example.com

P.S.: The disappearing of the dev mailing list from the Mailman web interface was because of directory permissions/ownerships.

Answer (score 0):

Change this in mailman.

From http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/mailman-install/node43.html

You should check the values for DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST and DEFAULT_URL_HOST in Defaults.py. Make any necessary changes in the mm_cfg.py file, not in the Defaults.py file. If you change either of these two values, you'll want to add the following afterwards in the mm_cfg.py file:

```
add_virtualhost(DEFAULT_URL_HOST, DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST)
```

You will want to run the bin/fix_url.py to change the domain of any existing lists.

Comment: I changed those two variables in
    /etc/mailman/mm_cfg.py
from lists.example.com to example.com

The line
add_virtualhost(DEFAULT_URL_HOST, DEFAULT_EMAIL_HOST)
was already there so I didn't have to add it.

Then ran:
/usr/lib/mailman/bin/fix_url.py

But it said:
This script is intended to be run as a bin/withlist script...

So I eventually ran:
withlist -l -r fix_url dev

Finally restarted the mailman service. Now on the web interface: http://lists.example.com/mailman/listinfo
the dev list has disappeared.